# Javascript not working in my site

Tags: javascript

I'm having big trouble making a website. For some reason in whatever I do I can never get javascript to work. Is there something I'm missing for 'enabling' this?

For example I copied a very simple thing exactly.
https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/boinE

In a test file this is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
</script>

<style>
.box {
  background-color: #218D9B;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.transform-active {
  background-color: #45CEE0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box transform">
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"></input>
</body>


</html>
```

Yet the button does nothing in my test file.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: that is because you jquery is missing

Comment: `$()` is not generic JavaScript, it is jQuery.  have you installed the jQuery library package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to making sure JQuery has been loaded you should also load your JQuery code(script tag) before the closing body tag or wrap it in a document ready function call. If JQuery has been loaded then what is happening is that the JQuery is being executed before the html element your are attaching the event to has actually been loaded. So basically the JQuery event can't see your button element yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});


});
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding it but this seems to have done the trick, it is now working.
So every time I use javascript in my site I have to begin my functions with $(document).ready(function(){
????

Comment: @CraigJones - You don't have to if you load it in a script tag right before your closing body tag.  I will try and expand more on my answer when I get done with the website I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

The `$()` is a jQuery shorthand for finding elements in DOM. Did you include the [jQuery Library](https://jquery.com/download/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
</script>

<style>
.box {
  background-color: #218D9B;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.transform-active {
  background-color: #45CEE0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box transform">
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"></input>
</body>


</html>
```

This happens as you did not include Jquery and tried using it.

Note additional script tag on the top of your script tag